# Print ordered table in R

Tags: r

Using a df like:

```
df <- tibble(dist = c(x,x,y,x,y), desc = c("txt","txt2","txt3","txt4,"txt5"), count = c(20,10,5,30,10))
```

How can I print a table for one `dist`, ordered by `count`:

```
desc   count
txt4   30
txt1   20
txt2   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(dist == 'x') %>% arrange(desc(count)) %>% select(-dist)

#  desc  count
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 txt4     30
#2 txt1     20
#3 txt2     10
```

Or in base R :

```
temp <- subset(df, dist == 'x', select = -dist)
temp[order(-temp$count), ]
```

Comment: Is there also a way to limit the number of rows returned, for when I'm using a large DF?

Comment: Yes, you can add `head` in the pipe, `%>% head(n = 10)` to return first 10 rows.